# Please excuse me

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, site-policy, ban

Posting because in response to a [comment](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19294/hippopotamus-egyptian-%e1%b8%ab%ea%9c%a3b-a-phonosemantic-calque#comment40753_19295) under [one of my questions](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19294/hippopotamus-egyptian-%e1%b8%ab%ea%9c%a3b-a-phonosemantic-calque), I received a notice in direct messages which discouraged me from posting, directing me to meta instead. And my comments have been deleted.

Who of you did this? Was it an automatic action or was my comment flagged?

The notice speaks of contributions in the plural, though the timely succession makes it very clear that it was in reaction to my comment.

- The question has -3 points, out of 150 odd views, no comments to that effect, no close votes, but a fairly involved response which has 9 points, including a vote by me.

How is that "ill-received"?

By the way, some stacks show up/downvotes if you click on the score. You might want to turn that on.

- The stack frequently receives petty questions like tattoo translation requests.

How is my question "unproductive" in comparison, given that I tried to show a fair amount of prior research with links and citations?

Do you just pull canned responses out of your patrol hat?

- I had pointed out once that the answer is completely missing the question. Upon which I was told that the question wasn't clear enough.
- I was also told that the question is pointless.

1. The question is aptly titled "Hippopotamus - Egyptian ḫꜣb - a phonosemantic calque?". It is closing with a clear statement of the question, since before the edits. That's impossible to miss. The answer misses ḫꜣb completely.
2. A tangential aspect which I had mentioned earlier caught their attention. So they reviewed that point and I reacted accordingly removing it from the question, after I had already redacted it once for being too wordy with relevant typological evidence. This is in line with their telling me that most of the question is irrelevant—irrelevant to the only point they felt compelled to refute, it turns out.
3. Eventually they deny the question, because "we understand the etymology of ἱπποπόταμος, and ḫꜣb does not actually solve the superficial weirdness with the word order". To which I tried respond that they do not, or at least they didn't show it.

   Either way I had to respond that they admitted failure responding to the question and didn't deserve accepting the answer (especially since they fail to acknowledge the quoted paragraph about phono-semantics).

How was that *harassment, bigotry, or abuse; unfriendly or unkind; no longer needed (outdated, conversational or not relevant)*; Or perhaps *Something else*? Try to be as specific as possible.

It is a waste of time I'm sure, if you are again going to miss the question again.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this answer addresses the core of your question.
Do ask for clarification if needed.

#### Moderators act as a team

Who did this?
We all did, as a team.
Bigger things like your moderator messages and suspensions always work like that.

It isn't even technically possible for any one moderator to issue suspensions or send moderator messages behind their colleagues' backs; we're all notified when anyone does anything major.
Also, the fact that you cannot tell which moderator was the one to click the button on your suspension or message is very much by design.

(Clarification for those that are unfamiliar with the concept: Moderator messages are a way for the moderator team to privately contact a user. Very few users ever see one.)

#### Our understanding of the community opinion

Our understanding is that the community on this site has long been frustrated with your contributions on the topic of etymology and would rather not have them around.
That is why we sent you a moderator message saying that you are no longer allowed to touch that topic at all on this site in questions, answers, or comments.

The understanding has been produced by numerous frustrated comments, flags, and downvotes on your etymological answers.
There is, of course, a chance that we have misconstrued what the community thinks.
That is why the moderator message stated that the only way to overturn the decision was for you to bring the topic up here on meta and ask if the community would actually prefer to allow you to continue contributing to etymology.
I'm happy to see this post of yours, as it brings a certain definiteness to the matter.

*If several users clearly indicate in this meta discussion that you should be allowed to continue your etymological writings on the site, then so be it.
If not, the ban stands.*

#### The long term

The topic ban is not a matter of a single post.
It is based on a long pattern of behaviour.

Restrictions were posed on your etymological contributions before and as a result of your overstepping those boudnaries you have been suspended a total of three times.
Once your postings recently resumed in a similar style after all that, we decided that a clear and complete ban on the topic is in order.
Your recent posts would not warrant this reaction from us alone, but they do demonstrate a lack of change in the direction we had hoped for.

What we hope is that your etymological posts start to be received well.
More on what that means later.

#### Ill-received

A question with a score of -3 certainly classifies as ill-received.
It is a strong sign that users would rather not have that bit of content on the site.
Another indicator of the reception is comments and flags as explained above.
It is notable that you have been challenged in comments many times but it seems to be vanishingly rare that anyone other than you supports your idea to the other commenters.
That is quite telling, and so is your very low reputation number in comparison to the number of answers you have posted.

Anyone with at least 750 reputation can see vote counts by clicking on the score of a post.
That feature, as far as I know, is active on all sites.

We do indeed use canned responses for some matters.
We have set up rules of thumb regarding, for example, the treatment of answers that should be deleted.
If an answer scores low enough, we leave a comment explaining that improvement is needed or it will be deleted.
There is no point in reinventing the wheel every time the need for such a comment arises.

It is not really the job of a moderator to be the arbiter of what is factually correct.
We will base much of our judgement on that on the votes and comments from other users.
The community is the arbiter of facts, and moderators are janitors that act when the community indicates that a clean-up is needed on a specific aisle.

#### What is welcome on this site?

The kind of content that is welcome on this site depends on many factors.
It should be within our scope, it should be interesting, it should be presented in good faith, and it should react to other users' comments and other opinions.
Our user base decides what is welcome.
Lawyering about technical validity of an argument is pointless if our users think that the content is just not good.
I can try to explain why I think voters have been unwelcoming to your post, but there is no way for me to lay out the exact criteria that triggered the reaction.

Human judgement is needed to keep a site like this interesting and useful to its users, and that is mostly exercised through votes and comments and flags.
We moderators then use judgement to act on those indicators.
We simply cannot codify what welcome content looks like; it has to be decided on how people feel about it.
You may argue that basing it all on such collective gut feelings is unfair or otherwise bad, but that's the way it is and that's the way I prefer it to be.
The wishes of the many outweigh the freedoms of the few in an environment like this, and that is not an unusual mechanism in other aspects of life either.

There is such a thing as a canon: certain rules of Latin grammar, etymology, history, and other things that are broadly considered to be valid.
It is certainly a little fuzzy around the edges, but there are core facts that are widely accepted.
The canon is decided on by the community, both on this site and more importantly in the broader Latin community across various countries and centuries.
You seem to be in the habit of going against that canon, and that can easily be irritating.
When doing so, you should hedge your statements appropriately and be transparent on the foundations on which your argument stands and where it contradicts the canon.
Extraordinary claims require extraordinary proof.
If other users are unimpressed by your arguments and consider the statements false, then that is a good indication that they probably are false and should probably be removed from the site.
You have shown little in the way of constructive reactions of criticisms of this point, and in my opinion that amply qualifies as unproductive.

You raise a good point about petty questions like translation requests for tattoos and similar.
Judging by votes, answers, and comments, our community seems to be quite happy with those questions.
They are not of stellar popularity and some of them do get shot down, but many of them are welcomed and get a nice answer or two.
They are evaluated on the same basis as your questions and answers:
Do our users welcome it on the site?

I am personally not an expert on etymology so I will leave addressing any technical matters on that to others.
But, frankly, I don't think discussing those details is central to this discussion.
To me this is a matter of the principles behind what is welcome and how the moderator team should react to what is not.

Comment: "We all did, as a team",  That is an answer to a different than I have asked. Pretty much as predicted. The next step is to tell me that I did this for myself. Bollocks.

Comment: "Our understanding is that the community on this site has long been frustrated with your contributions..." 2%! Besides,I find my way around on other stacks, too. Nonsense.

Comment: "The understanding has been produced by numerous frustrated comments, flags, and downvotes" That's an ignorant misrepresentation of the facts, eg. layed out in this question, which you have completely ignored.

Comment: "The topic ban is not a matter of a single post. It is based on a long pattern of behaviour." Again, utter nonsense. I have been inactive for months, Commented on one answer which concerned German rather than Latin, one question, and posted two questions. The other question has received no flack at all.

Comment: "Once your postings recently resumed in a similar style after all that, we decided that a clear and complete ban on the topic is in order." Well, I couldn't care less since you seem to be patently unable to deal with this type of question and essentially resort to insults. Fuck me, right?

Comment: @vectory A couple of points: (1) I'm not sure what your goal with this meta post is. If you're trying to win people over to undo the ban, a less combative style would serve you better. (2) A tiny fraction of visitors vote anyway. It's far more reasonable to compare the votes to the votes on other posts. -3 is an unusually low score, and 2% is not lower than elsewhere. (3) Yes, you have been inactive for a long time, but your resumed activity suffers from the same issues as your earlier contributions. Don't expect returning to your old routines after a long suspension to be taken neutrally.

Comment: *Sigh*, the three dovenvotes don't say what irked them. That's why a) I have to ask, as I did, for an apology, and b) the community guideless recommend comments to suggest improvements, which missing would suggest a missing sense of community c) absent which it seems to me that whatever sense of community you have is based on ulterior motives, not concerned with the technical matter of the question as you yourself have admitted, effectively. My question according to the format of the site is the barrage of comments that you had to delete.

Comment: My goal is therefore, to keep working on that question, in particular posting my own answer however stooped down without getting nuked. Because I am not technically banned.